# How to remove the last character on every line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

In NotePad++ how do I turn this:

```
GingeredRovinsky7|NTDc4MAODY3Mg|
```

into this:

```
GingeredRovinsky7=NTDc4MAODY3Mg
```

I know I can do a find and replace and replace the first `|` with `=`

However I need to strip the last `|` from each line as well.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every line is going to consist of exactly two `|` characters in that format, I should think this regex find-and-replace will do it.

Find all:

`^([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|$`

Replace all with:

`\1=\2`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression at the replace dialog.

Find:

```
.{1}$
```

Replace with nothing
Then just select Replace All

Full options are:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ supports extended and regular expression search and replace. Using the extended search and replace you could do this in two passes.

In the first pass replace the trailing `|` by searching for `|\r` and replacing with `\r`:

[image]

In the second pass we replace the middle `|` by doing a normal search and replace.

This of course assumes that your line ends are `\r\n`.