# In Notepad++, how do I remove characters after a certain character?

Tags: notepad++

In NotePad++, I want to remove everything after the third : character in a line.

So, the character would look like:

text:moretext:evenmoretext

How would I get rid of the evenmoretext?

Comment: use regex to search and replace

Comment: The text isn't the same every line.

Comment: that's not how regex works, it looks for a specific pattern

Comment: check this post: http://superuser.com/questions/339601/how-would-i-delete-the-first-27-characters-from-every-line-notepad?rq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/323258/how-to-remove-the-last-character-on-every-line-in-notepad?rq=1

Comment: Remove everything after the **second** ":"?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do so using Regexp search and replace

The regex to use is (put this into the `Find what` field on the Replace tab in the search window)

```
^([^:]*):([^:]*):.*$
```

And into `Replace with` enter

```
\1:\2
```

(if you need the ending : too, add it to the end of the `Replace with` string)

#### TL;DR

What does this all do?

This matches the beginning of the line:

```
^
```

This tells it to match a group, that consists of "everything that is **not** a `:` character"

```
([^:]*)
```

The literal `:` is matched by itself

And in the end, this matches "everything until the end of the line"

```
.*$
```

(the `$` matches the "end of the line")

And the replacement means "put in the **first** group matched, followed by a `:`, and then the **secound** group matched".